# What is the correct relative path for this ajax call?

Tags: ajax

I have an Ajax call in a script at myURL/db_interface/register_boat.php.

The call is to myURL/ajax/registerBoatAjax.php.  register_boat calls registerBoatAjax with

```
$.getJSON('../ajax/registerBoatAjax.php',all_query, function(data).
```

I have tried the above , `/ajax`, `../../ajax` and all the combinations I can think of, and $.getJSON never returns the JSON string.

The strange part is that if I move the ajax directory inside db_interface it works fine. But this is part of a bigger project and I want to have all the Ajax scripts together near root.

it's embarrassing to have this simple a problem stump me, and I have my best Dan Castalella "D-OH" all cued up.

Comment: Maybe different security settings on the ajax directory? What error do you get?

Comment: I suppose the above code part has a copy/paste issue: with that dot at the ends that's a syntax error.